# Bootstrap buttons not de-selecting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm using bootstrap to style buttons on my page, in Chrome 37 the buttons will not deselect after I have clicked them.

The offending button is simply:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

A full example can be found here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FFXEc/3/).

This same example works in firefox as expected. And I'm pretty sure was working in Chrome before the most recent update.

Is there a way to make this button work correctly in Chrome?

*Edit:*

The posts below fix the style of the button, but unfortunately don't fix the behaviour of the button.

If there is an action hooked up to onClick after the button is clicked the action will be re-triggered when return is pressed. This doesn't happen in firefox or older versions of chrome. [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FFXEc/11/).

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

and remove `background-color: #3071a9;` and `border-color: #285e8e;` from

```
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  /*background-color: #3071a9;
  border-color: #285e8e;*/
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFXEc/7/)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, when the button is clicked it stays in the clicked position. It also stays selected such that when you press return it will run the button's action.

If you checkout the jsfiddle link in my question in the most recent version of chrome you should be able to see the problem.

Comment: I don't see a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, there is a link just after the code example. Here it is again [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FFXEc/3/)

Comment: That seems to be a step in the right direction. The button is no longer selected, but still is looks depressed. What was the change?

Comment: It's in my answer. I added the css rules. That was your question so basically this questions is answered.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though the button does not look focused it still is focused and still looks depressed. What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 37.0.2062.124 m

Comment: I'm on the same version (minus the m?). I have tested this problem on a second computer also running the same version and was able to reproduce the problem. This change does not fully fix the button's behaviour on mouseup. If you try the original jsfiddle in firefox you should be able to see the correct behaviour.

Comment: That appears to fix the look, but lets assume the button as a onClick action attached. Hitting return after clicking the button will re-trigger the action. This doesn't happen in firefox or older versions of chrome: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFXEc/10/).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'm beginning to think this is just a bug with the most recent version of Chrome.

Comment: if you want to continue your investigations you should start a new post to get more attention. This post has got its answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.  The problem lied with the grouping of classes.

In the fiddle you provided, around line 95 you have this:

```
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3071a9;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}
```

If you break up the focus from the rest, it starts to work as you intend it to.

```
.btn-primary:focus {
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3071a9;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}
```

The cause of this is because once you've clicked on it, it enters the "focused" state until you click somewhere else.  Since your focus was the same as active and hover, it looked like it was still in the "active" state.

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFXEc/8/).

Comment: This change fixes the way it looks, but assuming there is an action hooked up to onClick after the button is clicked the action will be re-triggered when return is pressed. This doesn't happen in firefox or older versions of chrome. Fiddle example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FFXEc/11/).

Comment: I'm afraid that I might have done something wrong, but I can't seem to replicate the issue you're having.  I'm running Google Chrome version 37.0.2062.124.  What version are you running?